# Remove HTTP_COOKIE cookie from browser

Tags: asp-classic

How can I remove an HTTP_COOKIE cookie from the browser using classic ASP?

Comment: If you need to remove session cookies then check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19709928/421891

Answer (score 5):

```
Response.Cookies("cookie_name").Expires = DateAdd("d",-1,Now())
```

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is a user's property once it is sent to his computer. you cannot actually remove it manually from his/her computer as this would lead to security flaws. So the solution is using the expire property of a cookie. For example setting the cookie's expires property to a previous or older time, ensures that the browser automatically deletes/discards the cookie.
For eg:

```
 myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
```

Comment: How to get name of cookie from request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE")?

Comment: Request.Cookies["CookieName"]

Comment: Please remember to mark answered questions. Its most polite to reward those spending time on your problem.