# Classic ASP: Multiple session cookies

Tags: session, cookies

When I send request to web server, I have large number of request header cookies:

Cookie:ASPSESSIONIDSADTCDSQ=CCDNMFBBHKFONOBPMMCGOHND; ASPSESSIONIDSCCTDAQT=JJMDMBJDDEDNBDNGAIDIODCK; ASPSESSIONIDQABQBDQS=BCOLMOCCHFAMNOBPEMPKMOBD; ASPSESSIONIDSCDRCBQT=KMAJPCCAOPCAAIFDCHOEAILB; ASPSESSIONIDQQARDCRQ=AGLJDHAAOACFGNIIDEMEHLND;... and so on, about hundred of them or even more.

Why i have more than one and what sense does it has? Can i change this to send only one value?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web host? It appears multiple servers don't know each other exist. If you can't control the servers, you could possibly write an ASP function to delete all except one and refer to that one specifically. Also, if your users "Log Out" you will want to call Session.Abandon.

There's some more info here:
[Classic ASP: Multiple ASPSESSIONID in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783878/classic-asp-multiple-aspsessionid-in-cookies)